# Git log not showing anything

Tags: git

I made a new repository today, and make three or four commits. I noticed that `git diff` would not show my diffs, and `git log` is not returning any information. That said, I see that my `.git` directory does update with each commit:

```
$ git init
$ git add someFile.py
$ git commit -am "Initial commit"
$ vim someFile.py    
$ git commit -am "Refactor foo"
$ ls -l .git/
/home/dotan/code/foo/.git   Thu Mar 17 14:27:06 IST 2016   total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:15 branches
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users   19 Mar 17 14:26 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users   92 Mar 17 14:15 config
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users   73 Mar 17 14:15 description
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users   23 Mar 17 14:15 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:15 hooks
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users  137 Mar 17 14:26 index
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:15 info
drwxr-xr-x  3 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:16 logs
drwxr-xr-x 10 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:26 objects
drwxr-xr-x  4 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:15 refs

$ vim someFile.py
$ git commit -am "Update foo"
$ ls -l .git/
/home/dotan/code/foo   Thu Mar 17 15:00:00 IST 2016   total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotan TECHMARKETING\domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:15 branches
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan TECHMARKETING\domain^users   27 Mar 17 14:59 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users   92 Mar 17 14:15 config
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users   73 Mar 17 14:15 description
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users   23 Mar 17 14:15 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:15 hooks
-rw-r--r--  1 dotan domain^users  137 Mar 17 14:59 index
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:15 info
drwxr-xr-x  3 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:16 logs
drwxr-xr-x 13 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:59 objects
drwxr-xr-x  4 dotan domain^users 4096 Mar 17 14:15 refs
```

Furthermore, my last commit does show in the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file:

```
$ cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
Update foo
```

**What should I troubleshoot?** This is on Ubuntu 15.10. Git in other directories works just fine.

**EDIT:** Additional commands as requested in the comments.

```
$ git log
$ echo 'Another line' >> someFile.py
$ git diff
$ git branch -a
* master
$
```

**ADDITIONAL EDIT:** This problem affects all new Git repos on the machine that are created with `git init`. Git repos downloaded from Github and older Git repos created on the machine from one month ago are fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "`git log` is not returning any information"? What happens when you run `git log` exactly? And when do you try to use `git diff`?

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot/copy of your terminal output from `git log` and `git diff`?

Comment: When you edit a file you have to `git add`it again before you can commit it.

Comment: @ThomasStets The OP is using `git commit -a`. And `git diff` would show something if he forgot to add his file.

Comment: Thanks. I added the output of `git log` and `git diff`.

Comment: Well that's odd! What is the error code you get after `git log` or `git diff`?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` say ?

Comment: @ThibaultD.: Added to the bottom of the OP, thanks.

Comment: @dotancohen Any chance you have an invalid .gitconfig ? (Though `git diff` should output an error if the diff algorithm is invalid)

Comment: @J.P.Quenord-Zermingore: I don't think so. I just took a look at `~/.gitconfig` and compared it with other machines, looks fine. Also, all my other Git repos on the same machine work fine.

Comment: Well that's weird. I deleted my answer so that people can easily see that your question wasn't addressed. Would it be a great loss to delete your .git and perform git init again?

Comment: You could also try to delete your `.git/index`, it's a commonly used way of debugging state errors in a git repo.

Comment: Dumb question, but you haven't either succeeded in committing a .gitignore with "*" in it?

Comment: @ThibaultD.: No, there is no `.gitignore` file. I could lose the git history and init a new `.git/` directory, but I would actually like to take the opportunity to learn about the problems and fix it. I'll rm the index file when I'm back in the office. Thank you!

Comment: can there be any ownership issue? your ls shows different domains for new files

Comment: @ThibaultD.: After deleting `.git/index` the `git status` command shows the modified file as expected, but stubbornly `git log` and `git diff` still show no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After encountering this issue on another Ubuntu install, I simply tried updating Git via apt-get and the issue was resolved. **Apparently this is an Ubuntu-specific problem.**

```
$ sudo apt-get install git.
```